# Multiple jquery ajax on page not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I've got 2 ajax requests on one page. Both work fine on separate pages, but when they're both on the same page, one stops working after the first has been run.

I'm using the Colorbox plugin for one request and this works fine. The other I've put together myself (I'm new to jquery, so may well have errors) and works if I run it first. But once Colorbox has been activated it stops working.

The page is here: http://dev.thetram.net/times/test2.php and the code below.

Would really appreciate some pointers to where I'm going wrong, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {
$('#parkride').change(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
 url: "http://dev.thetram.net/inc/parkingfinder_script.asp",
 dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 data: "Action=GetPR&Val=" + $("#parkride").val(),
 async: false,
 success: function(msg) {
     $('#output').html("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
 }
 });
return false;
    });
  });


$(function() {
//if submit button is clicked
$('form#frm_journeyplanner #submit').click(function () {

//get form values
var str = $("form#frm_journeyplanner").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://dev.thetram.net/inc/journeyplanner/jp_testscript.asp",
 dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: str,
 async: false,
 success: function(msg) {
  $('#results').html(msg);
  $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#results", opacity:0.6, innerWidth:620, innerHeight:580, title:"Find tram times",
  onOpen:function(){  $("#results").show(); }, //make sure results show in the modal window
  onClosed:function(){ $("#results").hide(); } //stop results from displaying on the main page
   });
 }
 });
return false;
    });
  });

}); // end of doc ready
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debugged it and it's clear what the problem is.

The second ajax request will inject another HTML element (DIV in this case) with the same id="output" which will then cause the first ajax query on subsequent calls to put the result in that DIV instead of in the UL that you want.

How did I know? I used debugging tools provided with Google Chrome. I noticed that $("#output") (I made a watch expression for this) 'points' to the UL at first, but then as soon as second ajax request if finished, all of the sudden this same expression points to DIV element. Then I examined the return value of the second ajax request and indeed it's one DIV element with the id="output".

Don't forget - when you say $("#output") you might get *multiple* elements with the id="output". If you only want UL elements with that id, then you should specify that, otherwise you'll get back all elements with that particular id.

In short, what you want at the end of the first ajax query is:

```
$('ul#output').html("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
```

Comment: Ah that works a dream! Thanks for your help, that makes total sense now. I'd checked for duplicate names in each script but not realised that it would process it like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the

```
async: false
```

line. This tells jQuery to run the request *synchronously*, which blocks the browser until the request comlpetes.

Comment: If I remove it on both, Colorbox stops working. If I just remove it on the other call, it makes no difference

Comment: Any single 'async' call will block the browser. Async is generally not a good idea. Can you find an alternative to Colorbox?

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which script isn't working.

I'll assume it's the one attached to the #parkride. If so, that one works just fine for me in Chrome 9 (dev).

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very helpful! Yes its the parkride one that I'm having problems with. That's interesting, it's not working for me in Firefox

Comment: @sje397: he said they work in *separate pages*, the example page he provided has both of them. Apparently, the problem is more subtle since it works on my dev version of Chrome.

Comment: I've just tested it in Opera and Safari and have same problem

Comment: Bizarre. I've just tried it in IE9 beta and... it works. It also works in Firefox 4.0 b7.

Comment: All my tests are on a PC (I'm a PC! LOL)

Comment: hmm, is it possible it's a mac related issue? Does my code look ok? I was wondering if there was a problem with having more than one ajax event on the page?

Comment: To my (inexperienced) eyes your jQuery looks fine. I am not aware of any issue with multiple usages of jQuery's ajax in a single page. You're not even targeting the same server-side page so an error on the server should be unlikely. Anyway, why don't you fire up (pun intended) Firebug and see what's really going on here? I'm not talking about debugging JavaScript, just a simple network trace.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not really sure what i'm looking for?

Comment: Well, ultimately ajax is nothing but a HTTP request done asynchronously. So there's this network element in question - you're not simply calling a JavaScript function which does some work (by potentially calling other functions), if it were the case you could simply debug the thing and be done. You should verify that the HTTP POST is indeed made and if so what is the result of that request. Firebug's Net pane will show you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. Well it's interesting. The output is all perfect, but it doesn't seem to be outputting to the browser?

Comment: OK, then at least you've eliminated one part of the problem - HTTP POST is working fine and the result is returned fine. We're left with two choices - either jQuery can't find your target element (basically impossible) or maybe the text returned isn't valid HTML (not sure it even has to be). Do you have control over server side code (ugh, classic ASP?) - maybe you could try to return text wrapped in <span>? Take a look at the JavaScript console for any errors, something **must** be failing somewhere.

Comment: It's really weird. Tried wrapping it in a span and made no difference. I don't understand why it works fine until the other ajax request runs.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the original question! Once you run the second ajax request, the first one indeed is not working any more.